# VBA excel .Left .Top when picture is rotated

Tags: excel, vba, image, rotation

I tried countlessly but I still have this problem. I try to fit a picture in to a given range with a macro in excel. As long as the picture is not rotate (orientation  = 0) there's not a problem. But from the moment the picture gets rotated everything bleeds out. I have already discovered that the picture height and width are rotated as wel. But what happens to the .top and .left? Here's my code:

```
Function fotoInsert(ByVal PictureFileName As String, ByVal rng As Range)

    Set pic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PictureFileName)
    
    If pic.ShapeRange.Rotation = 90 Then
        With pic
              'keep original aspect ratio
              .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
              
              'Picture's aspect is less than rng aspect then adjust the picture's width to fit rng
             If (pic.Width \ pic.Height) <= (rng.Height \ rng.Width) Then
                 .Width = rng.Height - 1 'pictures' width is the larger height, by this line it fits exactly into range width
                 .Left = rng.Left + ((rng.Width - pic.Height) / 2)
                 .Top = rng.Top + 1
             Else 'Picture's aspect is greater than rng aspect then adjust the picture's height to fit rng
                 .Width = rng.Height - 1 'picture's heigth is larger than its width, this line makes it exactly fit int range height
                 .Top = rng.Top
                 .Left = rng.Left
             End If
        .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        .PrintObject = True
        End With
    Else
        With pic
         'keep original aspect ratio
         .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
         
         'Picture's aspect is less than rng aspect then adjust the picture's width to fit rng
            If (.Height \ .Width) <= (rng.Height \ rng.Width) Then
                
                .Width = rng.Width - 1 'pictures' width is the larger height, by this line it fits exactly into range width
                .Left = rng.Left + 1 'position at left range border
                .Top = rng.Top + ((rng.Height - pic.Height) / 2) 'position in center of range height
            Else 'Picture's aspect is greater than rng aspect then adjust the picture's height to fit rng
                .Top = rng.Top + 1 'position at upper border of the range[/color]
                .Height = rng.Height - 1 'picture's heigth is larger than its width, this line makes it exactly fit int range height
                .Left = rng.Left + ((rng.Width - pic.Width) / 2) 'position in center of range width
            End If
        .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        .PrintObject = True 'make sure picture gets printed
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

So the problem occurs in the very first If condition (rotation = 90)
In the other cases I don't seem to have a problem.

A typical range I use to test is:

```
"A7:N46"
```

Comment: Hi Infra, welcome to SO. That seems like a lot of code just to position an image, I think there's probably a simpler solution. Can you add to your post to say exactly what you need to do and what problem you're having? Are you wanting to literally resize an image to fit in a range of cells? Why is rotation an issue, do you receive images that are rotated?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your fast response!

What I try to do is to fit any given picture in a pre determined range. So yes, I also will receive rotated pictures.

The idea is that the user selects pictures (up to 4)  and automatically they are arranged and resized to fit in one pre-determined excel sheet. So I made 4 scenario's (with different ranges) how to arrange those pictures on one sheet. This is done in an other routine via a switch case.

So far this code works with non rotated pictures. From the moment there's a rotation in there it is getting messy and pictures 'bleed out'. If there's an other way to tackle my problem, I'm glad to here it.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem as described here. It is unclear what happens with top and left properties of the shaperange when rotation 90 or 270 occurs.

In case of rotation, my workaround was:

- create a new hidden sheet;
- insert the rotated picture;
- hard code the position of the picture;
- copy the rows to the range where you want it;
- delete the temporary sheet.